# I want a subdomain only accessible to some some specific computer in the local network

Tags: .htaccess, dns, webserver, cpanel

I'm trying to make a subdomain only accessible for some computer on our local network. But I don't find the best methode to do that

To do that, I tried to set up the subdomain directory using the .htaccess file by allowing our public ip. But see that it change everytime this is not a good idea.
So I want to know what is the best way to do that. 
Thank you

Comment: Set up a DNS server on your local network/configure that computer's hosts file to resolve that subdomain name; i.e. have no public DNS record for it. Note that that won't prevent any access, but it will somewhat obscure it. To do it properly you need to use authentication of some form or another.

Comment: In my point of view, setting up a DNS server is more secure. Thank you!